# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() loop

Tags: php, foreach

Hi Stackoverflow i hope you are all well today,

i seem to have run into an issue and am kindly requesting your assistance;

Basically i am using jQuery to manipulate a form, the form then stores in the session and upon returning to the page a foreach loop is used to return the values from the session into the page.

The issue is if I create more than one instance of this foreach loop it gives me an invalid argument (if i add the same code over and over again it works fine)

So firstly here is the code;

jQuery

```
    $(function(){
$('.add_child').click(function(){
    var attrName = $(this).attr('name');
    var count = $(this).attr('count');
    $(this).attr('count', (parseInt(count)+1))
    var input = $('<input />');
    var lineBreak = $('<br/>');
    input.attr('type','text')
    input.attr('name',attrName+"["+count+"]" ) 
    $('.children_form').append(input);
    $('.children_form').append(lineBreak);
})
$('.add_s_child').click(function(){
    var attrName = $(this).attr('name');
    var count = $(this).attr('count');
    $(this).attr('count', (parseInt(count)+1))
    var input = $('<input />');
    var lineBreak = $('<br/>');
    input.attr('type','text')
    input.attr('name',attrName+"["+count+"]" ) 
    $('.spouce_children').append(input);
    $('.spouce_children').append(lineBreak);
})
});
```

and the PHP / HTML CODE -> Button One (add_child)

Children, please name your natural and / or addopted children

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['children'] as $index=>$child){ ?>
<?php echo "<input type='text' name='children[{$index}]' value='{$child}'/>";?>
<?php } ?>

<input type="button" count='<?php echo count($_SESSION['children']);?>' name="children" class="add_child" value="Add Another Child"/>

<div class="children_form">
<?php //add the inputs here?>   
</div>
```

and the PHP / HTML CODE -> Button Two (spouce_children)

```
<label>Spouces Children, please name all natural and addopted children</label>
<input type="text" name="spoucechild" id="spoucechild" />

<?php foreach($_SESSION['spoucechild'] as $index=>$child){ ?>
<?php echo "<input type='text' name='spoucechild[{$index}]' value='{$child}'/>";?>
<?php } ?>

<input type="button" count='<?php echo count($_SESSION['spoucechild']);?>' name="spoucechild" class="add_s_child" value="Add Another Child"/>
<div class="spouce_children">
    <?php //add the inputs here?>     
</div>
```

I would like to thank you for any help you can / will provide <3

Error Occurs here:

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['spoucechild'] as $index=>$child){ ?>
```

Comment: What line of your code gives the error? My guess is your session isn't always initialized so you get an invalid argument because it doesn't exist

Comment: oh yes sorry i get an error here, ill edit the above

Comment: You realise it's spelt "spouse"?

Comment: yes i know lol, im not worried about spelling at this stage

Comment: do u have a `start_session()` on top of page? do an `print_r($_SESSION['spoucechild'])`

Comment: <?php foreach($_SESSION['spoucechild'] as $index=>$child){ ?>

Comment: @kjy112 - should be session_start() but that's the question I was going to ask. @Xavier - it's not clear how your PHP is called. Are you calling it through AJAX or is the form being submitted?

Comment: Sorry guys i've figured it out, i was making a foreach call to a session element that wasn't in the session !

Comment: @Xavier: Glad to hear you solved it. But, in the future, decorating the line you're having trouble with and the error in question being returned in the post would be very helpful to anyone that's trying to assist. ;-)

Comment: @Xavier, thats why you have to check with isset() if the session exists before doing anything with it.

Comment: @Brad Christie, i have highlighted the error in the posting.

Comment: @Xavier: I realize that, I'm just making a recommendation for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Xavier: You could try --

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['spoucechild'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['spoucechild'] as $index=>$child){
        echo '<input type="text" name="spoucechild[' . $index . ']" value="' . $child . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```